# Can a Homebrew formula accept options with values for `install`, like `--foo=bar`?

Tags: macos, homebrew

I know that a Homebrew formula can check Boolean options (`--with-foo`, `--without-bar`) passed to `brew install`.

Can `brew install` accept options with values, like `--foo=/path/to/bar`?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @mipadi, i would like to pass the path to an alternative binary to be used in the build.

Comment: I'm also looking for the same thing. If someone has an answer that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out you can use `ARGV.value`.

e.g.

```
option "with-bin-path=", "Path for binary path"
# ...
binpath = ARGV.value("with-bin-path")
```

See https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/1803

Comment: Seems `ARGV.value` is outdated, any alternative?