# Formula options with values

Tags: homebrew

Can homebrew formula accept options that has values?
i.e.: `brew install somepkg --daemon-user=_www`

We can then use `_www`, to modify a `plist`,
or even use `inreplace` to replace
default user in some `.conf`

I know that there is already a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22564690/can-a-homebrew-formula-accept-options-with-values-for-install-like-foo-bar) asking that exact problem,
but no-one seems to know :(

Comment: I'm also looking for the same thing. If someone has an answer that would be greatly appreciated.